# How to make a parameter stochastic in a differential equation system with NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

I constructed the differential equation system below, which I solved using NDSolve. Now I need one parameter ($mu$) to be stochastic, e.g. Poisson distributed around a mean and changing slightly at every time step.
This is my current model, which is now fully deterministic:

```
sol[fmaxnW_?NumericQ, fminnW_?NumericQ, fmaxpW_?NumericQ,fmaxnR_?
NumericQ,fminnR_?NumericQ, micW_?NumericQ, micR_?NumericQ,kW_?NumericQ, kR_?
NumericQ , K_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ,mu_?NumericQ, Amax_?
NumericQ,w_?NumericQ, pinit_?NumericQ, tinit_?NumericQ, propR_?NumericQ] :=
Module[{},
 s = NDSolve[
{A'[t] == -w*A[t],
 nW'[t] == (fmaxnW - ((fmaxnW - fminnW)*(A[t]/micW)^kW)/((A[t]/micW)^kW - fminnW/fmaxnW))*
           Which[A[t] < micW, (1 - 1/K (nW[t] + pW[t] + nR[t])), True, 1]*nW[t] -
           a*1/K (nW[t] + pW[t] + nR[t])*nW[t]  +  b*pW[t] -
           w*nW[t] - mu*(fmaxnW - ((fmaxnW - fminnW)*(A[t]/micW)^kW)/((A[t]/micW)^
          kW - fminnW/fmaxnW))*nW[t],

 pW'[t] == fmaxpW*pW[t]  +  a*1/K (nW[t] + pW[t] + nR[t])*nW[t]  - b*pW[t] - 
           w*pW[t] - mu*fmaxpW*pW[t],

 nR'[t] == (fmaxnR - ((fmaxnR - fminnR)*(A[t]/micR)^kR)/((A[t]/micR)^kR - fminnR/fmaxnR))*
           Which[A[t] < micR, (1 - 1/K (nW[t] + pW[t] + nR[t])), True, 1]*nR[t] - 
            w*nR[t] + mu*(fmaxnW - ((fmaxnW - fminnW)*(A[t]/micW)^kW)/((A[t]/micW)^kW - 
            fminnW/fmaxnW))*nW[t] + mu*fmaxpW*pW[t],

 A[0] == 0, WhenEvent[Mod[t, 24] == 0, A[t] -> Amax],
 pW[0] == pinit*(1 - propR), 
 nW[0] == (tinit - pinit)*(1 - propR),  nR[0] == tinit*propR
 },
{A, nW, pW, nR}, {t, 0, 240}];
 Return[s]] 

sol[1, -6, 0.00001, 0.9, -6, 0.01, 0.05, 1, 1, 
 5*10^9, 0.0001, 0.14, 8*10^(-8), 0.02, 0.231, 1, 2*10^5, 0]
```

How can I implement stochastic variation in the model parameter $mu$ in a simple way?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want `mu` to be a different (random) value in each call to `sol`? Or do you want `mu` to change at every time step in `NDSolve`? Or change at random times in `NDSolve`?

Comment: _"and changing slightly at every time step"_ isn't well defined because:1) Time steps can be adaptative and 2) "changing slightly" doesn't have a precise meaning

Comment: @belisariushassettled. When I phrased it in that way, I had in mind numerical solutions to stochastic differential equations where the time step is fixed (non-adaptive), and the `mu` might some be something like a Wiener increment. I suspect that's not actually what the OP wants, but, you know, I figured I'd throw it out there.

Comment: @march I was referring to the question phrasing, not yours :) ... Double :)

Comment: @belisariushassettled. I figured! But perhaps some extra comments on the post might encourage the OP to give us more details. :)

Comment: I'm sorry the question was not clear. I want $mu$ to change over time stochastically, which can be at every time step of NDSolve or simply at a certain small time step (how small exactly does not really matter). As $mu$ represents a mutation rate between 2 different subpopulations and mutation is a random process, I want to incorporate that randomness into my model

Comment: Ok, voting to reopen. Here's a way: `sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == Sin[w[t] t], x[0] == 0, w[0] == 0,
   WhenEvent[Mod[t, .1] == 0, 
    w[t] -> RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]]]}, x, {t, 10}, 
  DiscreteVariables -> {w}]; Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}]`

Comment: Or better: `sol := NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == Sin[w[t] t], x[0] == 0, w[0] == 0,
    WhenEvent[Mod[t, .1] == 0, 
     w[t] -> RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]]]}, x, {t, 10}, 
   DiscreteVariables -> {w}];
Plot[Through[Flatten@Table[sol, {6}][t]], {t, 0, 10}, 
 Evaluated -> True]`

Comment: Mathematica support various [stochastic differential equation processes](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/StochasticDifferentialEquationProcesses.html), which may be of help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Why not use `ParametricNDSolve` and make mu a parameter; you could then compute the sensitivity. Would that not allow for a much deeper analysis?